# Custom sort ssrs matrix

Tags: reporting-services

I have a matrix report that has four columns and is sorted descending on the last columns values. The problem I have is when there is a tie I would like to use the value in the prior column or the one prior to that if there is still a tie. Below is a sample of my output and what I'm after is for Nissan and Renault to be switched. This is the expression I'm currently using in my group sort

```
=IIF(Fields!YearSold.Value = MAX(Fields!YearSold.Value),0, Fields!UnitSold.Value)

            2009    2010    2011    2012
Make        Units   Units   Units   Units
Chevy       1,104   842     811     927
Volvo       1,054   905     792     879
Ford        1,638   923     718     809
Nissan        918   794     725     791
Renault       840   698     759     791
Mazda         722   535     460     621
Lexus         786   590     551     563
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting that for me Polygnome

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a tablix on multiple columns. Edit the tablix Sort properties, adding the additional columns in order - the tablix will be sorted that order, starting with the top column.

[image]

Comment: Does your report have any row groups? There may be sort properties set on the group(s) that override the tablix sort settings.

Comment: I need to sort on the most current year(2012 in this case) and this is a dynamic column name so I need to sort in my MakeName group so I can use an aggregate to determine the most current year. SSRS wont allow aggregates in sort on the tablix properties. I tried your method and hard coded years into my expression and it would only sort on 2009. I'm close with my row group expression but SSRS seems to default to sorting alphabetically after the initial sort when there is a tie for unit value, that's what I need to correct, but it seems I can only use one sort expression.

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood - so you have a column group which is grouped on Year and you need to sort by the most recent year, followed by the previous year, the year before that etc? Please can you provide the following info: The parameters of the report and any associated datasets, the columns of your main dataset for the matrix and what grouping(s) you have created in the report. That will help in determining what options you have to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the help Nathan but I ran out of time and switched to a pivot in my query and a table for the report. I have more reports of this nature to write so when I get some free time I'll explore it some more. Thanks again.